# Update Github files through the REST API

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I'm working on a personal website builder. *My goal is to be able to manipulate my page within the browser and then hit a 'Publish' button and have the new HTML file to be committed to the Github repository where my code is hosted.*

I've been able to figure out everything up to generating the updated HTML. However, after going through the GitHub documentation I could not really understand how files should be processed prior or committed to the repository using the API. Could someone please help me out?

PS: I'd be using **JavaScript** to generate the HTML and for API calls. *Also if there is a better method to achieve my goal I'm open to those too.*

Answer (score 6):

Use [GitHub API v3 Repository Content endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)

You need to take into account the following:

- The content of the file should be in base64 encoding.
- If the file already exists, you need to provide the blob **SHA** of the file, you can get it via [Get repository content endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content).

Here is a working example with Node.js with Octokit API using **createOrUpdateFileContents** method. Read more about it [here](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-create-or-update-file-contents)

This endpoint will create a new commit with the new file content, you can even specify the committer and the author.

| Update File Content in GitHub | [<kbd>View in Runme [image]</kbd>](https://app.runme.dev/cell/cll4e4kup000ds601yglro8ir) |
| --- | --- |

```js
// The content of the file should be base64
const content = Buffer.from(`Hello world at ${new Date().toUTCString()}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');

// If the file already exists, you need to provide the sha in order to update the file content.
const file = await octokit.rest.repos.getContent({
    owner: owner,
    repo: repo,
    path: path,
    branch: branch,
    });
const { sha } = file.data;
const fileContent = await octokit.rest.repos.createOrUpdateFileContents({
   owner,
   repo,
   path,
   sha: sha,
   message: 'This is the commit message generated via GitHub API',
   content,
   committer: {
     name: 'demo',
     email: 'demo@example.com'
   },
   author: {
     name: 'demo',
     email: 'demo@example.com'
   }
 });

const { commit: { html_url } } = fileContent.data;

console.log(`Content updated, see changes at ${html_url}`);
```